# Unable to get entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder in jpa with eclipselink

Tags: java, jpa

NOTE : This may sound duplicate but I have tried all possible methods

I am working on eclipse link with jpa (learning JPA) and came to know that JPA is not supporting `EnitityManager#getCriteriaBuilder()`. I am getting this error

```
The method getCriteriaBuilder() is undefined for the type EntityManager
```

Following is my dependencies

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.38</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.4</version>
        </dependency>
```

But when I checked [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/gjitv/index.html), doesn't says about the deprecation of method.Any help will be useful

And I am using all this on `J2SE` project

Thanks

following is my persistence.xml

```
<persistence-unit name="simple-insert_fetch">
        <class>com.model.Employee</class>
        <properties>
            <!-- Configuring JDBC properties -->
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/jpa_studies" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="root" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <!-- <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" -->
            <!-- value="drop-and-create" /> -->
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
```

Following is the code I am using to fetch Result
Crite

```
riaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Employee> query = builder.createQuery(Employee.class);
        Root<Employee> employee = query.from(Employee.class);
```

Comment: Could you post your persistence.xml and the code where the error throws

Comment: @BrunoDM I just updated

Comment: What about the code?

Comment: You should use jpa version 2.0

Comment: the persistence.xml seems to be missing the provider attribute: `<provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>` should be the right value if you want to use eclipselink

Comment: @digit thanks now I got it, was thinking `1.02` is `jpa2` :)